# Wait for a child of class in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, roblox

I'm making a Chrome Extension for [Roblox](https://roblox.com/games), and I need to wait for all of the children of a certain element to load so I can do stuff with them. Currently, this logs all of the elements as they are added, but I need to dig deeper in their children to find class "game-card-name", but it seems to be non-existent whenever I do `$(e).find("game-card-name")`

```
console.log("Roblox Bookmark Loaded");

$(document).on("DOMNodeInserted", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass("game-card")) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

What I need is a way to search *in jQuery*, and wait for an element to exist, and possibly yield until an attribute is present. If anyone has a *jQuery* answer, please post!

**EDIT: I was not doing $(e.target). I solved this**

Comment: _"but it seems to be non-existent whenever I do `$(e).find("game-card-name")`"_ The code at Question checks for `if ($(e.target).hasClass("game-card"))`. Is the issue that you are trying to match the incorrect `.className`? Which `.className` are you checking for?

Comment: I do `$(e).find("game-card-name")` inside of the if statement. Sorry if I was unclear. @guest271314

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FIHHPMNA2SFF

Comment: You dismissed @spanky 's Answer, though their Answer is accurate as to that specific issue at code at Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *but I need to dig deeper in their children to find class "game-card-name", but it seems to be non-existent whenever I do `$(e).find("game-card-name")`*

You're missing the `.` in the selector to find the class.

```
//---------v
$(e).find(".game-card-name")
```

Your selector was looking for elements with the *tag name*, like `<tame-card-name>`.

Comment: jQuery doesn't care about the "." in find, and adding the "." did not help me. Whenever I log the text, it logs nothing (with the blue 66 next to it, because there are 66 different elements with the class upon the first load for me)

Comment: @AlreadyPro: jQuery uses and builds upon the Selectors API that is used both for CSS and JS selector engines, so jQuery certainly does need the `.` when performing selection based on class name.

Comment: There's not enough info in the question to know what else may be the problem.

Comment: Although that is true, it still didn't solve my question.

Comment: @AlreadyPro: Unfortunately we can't solve problems that we can't see. You'll need to provide a complete example and a description of the results of the debugging you've already performed.